# Error encoding to Flash video

Tags: flash, directx, directshow, quicktime

I get an error message when trying to use Flash encoder that says " A required library did not initialize properly. Please insure you have Direct show 9 and Quick time 7 or higher installed on your system. But when I check I see that I have Direct X11 installed and no problems are shown. What happened>

Answer (score 1):

You should install QuickTime, it's not a part of DirectX.